# Fatal error: Cannot declare class XMLParser, because the name is already in use in C:\Apache24\htdocs\inc\class_xml.php on line 17

Tags: php, apache, webserver, mybb

I'm not that familiar with hosting webservers, but I hosted one using Apache24 in order to start workign on making my [MyBB forum](https://mybb.com/). I followed the [install guide](https://docs.mybb.com/1.8/install/) to the letter, but when i try going to localhost/install on my browser, I get the error in the title:

> Fatal error: Cannot declare class XMLParser, because the name is
> already in use in C:\Apache24\htdocs\inc\class_xml.php on line 17.

Using Command F, I went through every PHP file in the \install directory, and none of them seem to be declaring XMLParser. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was a PHP 8 incompatibility and patched. You can check the changes diff for this particular issue here in this commit:
https://github.com/mybb/mybb/pull/4095/commits/0da07eba1860a357ad9049223980d83895d57e84